# How to convert object to list in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I want to convert my object to list while passing as param to my API. I am not sure how to achieve this.
I tried Object.keys but not getting expected output.

```
Object.keys(myobj).map(function(key){
---logic
});
```

I am receiving list of objects from API:

```
[{Name : "sachin",Age  : 30},{Name : "Ramesh",Age  : 35}]
```

In Angular, when I use find method it is converted as object from the above list and it looks like below.

```
 {Name : "sachin",Age  : 30}
```

Now I have to change Age property value as 42 and pass it to API as list.

```
[{Name : "sachin",Age  : 42}]
```

Can someone help me to achieve this result.

Comment: Can't you just do [obj] ?

Comment: Use filter instead of find

Comment: @tano - In Angular, I need only one item as Object but API expects list so again I need to convert as list.

Comment: @fqrd I tried declaring an array and assigning this object to that array but still it is object only.

Comment: I see, and the filter gives it back to you with a singe item in case you have proper filter option

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
var payload = [{...prevObject,...{
  Age: 42
}}];
```

**prevObject** is object returned from *find* method.

Basically, the `...`  (spread operator) is used to merge the two objects into one.

Comment: Thanks Much. It is working. Why we need ... before objectname and propertyname.

Comment: The `...` is called *spread syntax* (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: You don't have to spread this twice, `{ ...prevObject, Age: 42 }` should suffice.